# My custom widget won't stay in the widget area after I refresh the widget page

Tags: php, widgets, sidebar

As the title says, i've been developing a simple image rollover widget, now that I'm almost done, the widget won't stay in the sidebar areas after I drag and drop it in and refersh the page, any idea what's going on?

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Rollover Widget
 * Description: A widget that creates a rollover image effect with a hyperlink.
 * Version: 0.1
 * Author: Zak Elas
 * Author URI: http://dot.com
 */


add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_widget' );


function my_widget() {
    register_widget( 'MY_Widget' );
}

class MY_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    function MY_Widget() {
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'example', 'description' => __('A widget that creates a rollover image effect with a hyperlink. ', 'example') );

        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 300, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'Rollover Widget' );

        $this->WP_Widget( 'example-widget', __('Rollover Widget', 'example'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );

        //Our variables from the widget settings.
        $link =  $instance['link'] ;
        $image = $instance['image'];
        $rollover_image = $instance['rollover_image'];

        echo $before_widget;

        // Display the widget link 

        echo $before_link . $link . $after_link;

        //Display the name 


         echo '<div id="test">
              <a href="'.$link.'">
              <img class="bottom" src="'.$image.'" />
              <img class="top" src="'.$rollover_image.'" />
              </a>
              </div>'; 


        echo $after_widget;
    }

    //Update the widget 

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;

        //Strip tags from link and name to remove HTML 
        $instance['link'] = strip_tags($new_instance['link']);
        $instance['image'] =  strip_tags($new_instance['image']);
        $instance['rollover_image'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['rollover_image']);

        return $instance;
    }


    function form( $instance ) {

        //Set up some default widget settings.
        $defaults = array( 'link' => __('Example', 'example'), 'image' => __('/images/editorial.png', 'example') , 'rollover_image' => __('/images/editorial.png', 'example') );
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>


        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'link' ); ?>"><?php _e('link', 'example'); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'link' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'link' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['link']; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
        </p>


        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image' ); ?>"><?php _e('image', 'example'); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'image' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['image']; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'rollover_image' ); ?>"><?php _e('rollover_image:', 'example'); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'rollover_image' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'rollover_image' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['rollover_image']; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
        </p>



    <?php
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID Base should be passed to WP_Widget class constructor as shown in the following code, You have passes wrong id "example-widget" which does not match with "id_base", also don't add spaces in id base. Replace MY_Widget() function with following modified function and it will work.

```
function MY_Widget() {
    $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'example', 'description' => __('A widget that creates a rollover image effect with a hyperlink. ', 'example') );

    $control_ops = array( 'width' => 300, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'rollover-widget' );

    $this->WP_Widget( 'rollover-widget', __('Rollover Widget', 'example'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
}
```